# Calling the result of a Callback function (or the Callback function itself) in other function

Tags: matlab, callback, togglebutton

I have a function that generates a sine-wave. The output is displayed in a GUI. In that GUI I have a toggle button. The toggle button function, when pressed, filters the wave and make further calculations like RMS. Now what I need is to display the resulting waveform when the toggle button is pressed.

```
%Calling the result of a GUI Callback function (or the Callback function itself) in
%other function
%=====================
% START USER CODE

function update_display(hObject,eventdata,hfigure)

. 
. 
.

if (toggle_button_IS_pressed) {X is Result of the button Callback function}

    else if (toggle_button_ISNOT_pressed){X is somethingelse}
    end
end
end


% --- Executes on button press in togglebutton8.
function togglebutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to togglebutton8 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
X = SomeKind of equation;
end
```

Comment: Please state your question using words...

Comment: @excaza I have further elaborated the question

Comment: You can check Value property of togglebutton in update_display function.